# How to export all collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Can someone please  tell me how to export all collections (into JSON Format) at a time through Command line

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow!**  Please take a few minutes to check out the [tour] and there are also important tips in [ask] as well as tips about **providing examples** at [mcve].  We like to see that some effort has been made in finding a solution before asking for help (on a _specific_ problem), so please includes details about what you've tried so far.  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Steve's script generates the files with quotes at the ends. For this to not happen, the pattern is improved.

Improving the above script

```
#!/bin/bash

DB=$1
Collections=$(mongo localhost:27017/$DB --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames()" | sed 's/[^"[:alnum:]]/ /g')

for collection in $Collections; do
   mongoexport -d $DB -c $collection -o ./$collection.json
done
```

Comment: You should exit your answer to explain what issue you had and why this is an  improvement.

Comment: I edited the answer Wayne. Thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to use mongoexport or mongodump but each of those only works on a single collection.

To get all collections and export them all you need to run some type of script that can locate and then loop through everything.
On linux it would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DB=$1
Collections=$(mongo localhost:27017/$DB --quiet --eval "db.getCollectionNames()" | sed 's/,/ /g')

for collection in $Collections; do
   mongoexport -d <DATABASE_NAME> -c $collection -o $collection.json
done
```

You'll need to this into a script file and then run it.
I haven't tested the above myself but it is hopefully error free.